# How to Change A Label's Text From Another View Controller and Save it With Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have a Input(UITextfied) and i want the data in it to change `DesA` in My other ViewController

My First ViewController: Facial (where the label `DesA` is)
My Second ViewController: ServiceAChangeViewController (where The Input and button is)
(sorry for the weird names)

Essentially i want to write a text in my `UITextField`, then click a button that saves it using core data and then changes the `DesA` label in my First View Controller

I followed some tutorials on youtube and wrote this code

Second ViewController(ServiceAChangeViewController):
var score = Facial(nibName: nil, bundle: nil).TitleChange
        var OutputLabel = Facial(nibName: nil, bundle: nil).DesA

````
  ```  @IBAction func saveData(_ sender: Any) {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Entity", in: context)
        let newEntity = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

        newEntity.setValue(score, forKey: "titleA")


        do {
            try context.save()
            print("saved")
        } catch {

            print("Failed savign")

        }

    }

    func getData() {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {

            if let result = try? context.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject] {
                for data in result  {
                    score = data.value(forKey: "titleA") as! String
                }


        } else {

            print("Failed")
        }

    }
    }


    @IBAction func SubmitAnswer(_ sender: Any) {
        OutputLabel?.text = score
        score = String(InputA.text!)

    }






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            getData()
        OutputLabel?.text = score

    }```
````

First ViewController(Facial):

```
    @IBOutlet var TitleA: UILabel!
    var TitleChange = String()










    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {







 }
```

But When I run the app and enter the text, it doesn't seem to change it nor save it.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this for saving core data entity, you also can use "didset" for variable

```
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
let newInfo = Entity(entity: Entity.entity(), insertInto: context)

// do something with entity

do {
try context.save() } catch let error as NSError {
print("Error... \(error), \(error)")
}
```